# Вывод символов строки в обратном порядке

Tags: c, строки

Не получается написать программу, которая читает строку входных данных,  а  затем печатает эту строку в  обратном  порядке.  По условию можно  запоминать  входные  данные  в  массиве  значений  типа  `char` ;  предполагается ,  что  строка  со стоит  не  более  чем из 255  символов.  Нужно обязательно воспользоваться  функцией `scanf()`  со спецификатором  %с ,  чтобы  выполнять  посимвольное  считывание  с устройства  ввода. Как?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

    char str[255];
    int i, j;

    printf("Введите строку:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
       scanf("%c", &str);
    for (j = strlen(str); j >= 0; j--)
        printf("%c", str[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Вот так получается:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

    char str[255];
    int i, j;

    printf("Введите строку:\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    //for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
       //scanf("%c", &str);
    for (j = strlen(str); j >= 0; j--)
        printf("%c", str[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

а через спецификатор %с, посимвольно, как по условию задачи - нет..??

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что это домашнее задание, и автор не приложил ни малейших усилий для его решения.

Comment: "Напоминаем о том , что вы можете воспользоваться функцией sc an f () со спецификатором %с" - это - жуть, а это: "после каждого нажатия клавиши генерируется символ новой строки (\n)" - бред.

Comment: На самом деле, можно предположить, что  автора просто сбили этими дурацкими словами про scanf и генерацию... Вторую часть задания -- (печать) он практически правильно сделал. Если бы не подсказки и в первой ввел бы тривиальным fgets-ом и не морочил голову ни себе ни людям. // Ау, автор! Надеюсь этот комментарий  поможет.

Comment: я только начал изучать Си, и все свои попытки в рамках того, что изучил попытался описать

Comment: Вообще-то просто чуть внимательней. Вы вводите в цикле `scanf("%c", &str)` Не кажется странным, что все время в одно и то же место? На самом деле для начала напишите, например, `&str[i]`. Это уже будет значительно лучше. Потом вспомните, что строку (это в данном случае str[]) надо завршать нулем. Кроме вас на каждой итерации  его никто не запишет. Ну, и выходить из цикла наверное надо все-таки не обязательно прочитав все 255 символов ввода, а можно и пораньше, например обнаружив, что очередной введенный символ это `\n`, можно сделать `break`. И т.д. и т.п. / Удачи!

Comment: Комментарий avp мне понравился, спасибо! Буду пробовать. Однако break по материалу книги еще не пройден, а значит предполагается выход из цикла каким-то другим способом??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> char str[255];
> ```

255 символов в строке и ещё нолик - так что надо 256.

```
char str[256];
```

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
>   scanf("%c", &str);
> ```

Взятие адреса массива - это неправильно. Массив - это уже адрес первого символа.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    scanf("%c", str);
```

Условие выхода - это перевод строки, а не достижение 255 символов:

```
for (i = 0; scanf("%c",str), *str!='\n'; i++);
```

Дальше, символы надо писать последовательно, а не все в нулевую позицию:

```
for (i = 0; scanf("%c",str+i), *str[i]!='\n'; i++);
```

Строка должна заканчиваться нулевым байтом.
После цикла i указывает на перевод строки, а он нам не нужен, заменяем ноликом:

```
str[i] = 0;
```

> ```
> for (j = strlen(str); j >= 0; j--)
>   printf("%c", str[j]);
> ```

Длина уже есть в i - можно её и использовать.

```
while(--i != -1)
  printf("%c", str[j]);
```

или так

```
for(--i; i--; )
  printf("%c", str[i]);
```

Для вывода символа лучше воспользоваться `putchar`'ом, а не `printf`'ом:

```
while(--i != -1)
  putchar(str[i]);
```

А вообще, я бы использовал указатели, а не индексы:

```
char s[256], p;
for(*(p=s+255)=0; p>s && (scanf("%c",--p), *p!='\n'); );
puts(p);
```

Кажется, требования задания выполнены?

Comment: Спасибо! Отличные советы!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>  // for strlen
#define SIZE 256

int main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
char line[SIZE];
int i;

printf("Введите строку:\n");
for (i = 0; scanf("%c", &line[i]) == 1 && line[i] != '\n'; i++)
    ;
line[i] = '\0';
for (i = strlen(line) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%c", line[i]);

return 0;
}
```